# What bottom bracket fits a Truvativ E450 crank?

Tags: crankset, bottom-bracket, sram

My bike has a crank that is so cheap that you won't find it mentioned on SRAM's web pages. This cheap crank is a Truvativ E450, and it has a square taper bottom bracket that is worn out and needs replacement. I have however noticed that there are multiple types of square taper bottom brackets, and since SRAM's web pages provide no useful information I was wondering if anyone could answer what kind of bottom bracket this crank uses?

Comment: Take out the current one and see if the measurements are on it. The kind of bottom bracket is dependent on both the frame and the crankset.

Answer (score 2):

It's just an older style of BB. It's a square taper BB. Simply remove it and it should indicate width of the axle and the cup size (very likely 68mm). Then go order a Shimano BB-UN52 for less than $20 online. It'll outlast the rest of the bike. BTW, you can still find these cranksets on ebay. Good luck!

Comment: Pro tip: If it doesn't have numbers or you don't want to disassemble the bottom bracket before getting the new one, you can use a ruler to find out the measurements.